# azure active directory services - mydomain.lan will it work?

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services

I'm looking at using azure active directory domain services to replicate our accounts upto Azure in order to be able to use our local domain accounts to authenticate against services like dropbox, dynamics CRM and possibly google apps.  Ive installed the connect software and all of the accounts have been pulled in.

some of the articles i have seen talk about setting dns records up on the public fqdn but we do not have one, we run mydomain.lan

Is it possible to get these accounts to authenticate in Azure if no domain?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, but it will be synchronized to your .onmicrosoft.com domain name.

see this explanation.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/How-to-prepare-a-non-routable-domain-such-as-local-domain-for-directory-synchronization-e7968303-c234-46c4-b8b0-b5c93c6d57a7?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

In short if you want to synchronize to a public custom domain such as -ed-baker.co.uk you need to ensure the users to sync have a UPN containing a publically routable domain name.

To do this you can either use PowerShell or the Users and Computers gui (or ADAC if using a server that has it installed)

If not you will get users synched to your Microsoft online default domain.

Hope that helps, please mark as the answer if it does.

Yours

Ed